# Jquery loading site with a modal in

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I come today with a little issue jquery related, I'm still learning so please bear with me.

I'm making a site (site1.html) with bootstrap, within this site I have another considerably big one (site2.html) which I'm loading with jquery inside a div:

```
<div id="siteloader"></div>  
<script> 
$("#siteloader").html('<object data="site2.html">'); 
</script>
```

site2.html has a fullscreen modal but when I use it it takes only the full width/height of the div not of the whole site.

Is it anyway to make it so it takes the full window? or should I just join the small htm1 and big html2?[image: what happens]

Comment: The thing is that you use an `<object>` tag to display nested browsing context. See documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object). I would try to use jQuery [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to load the `html2` into `#siteloader`... instead of `.html()` and an object tag. Now It's not sure that will work without any other new issues... But try this way. ;)

Comment: Are `html1` and `html2` two diffrent domain names? And if so, do you own both?

Comment: They are both mine, I can modify them as I please.

Comment: Ok... So that should work with `.load()`... But you will also need to add a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to `html2` to allow access from `html1`. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work).

Comment: Yes, it worked using .load(). I'll read all the documentation at depth. Thank you!

Comment: Great! happy coding ;)